# How do I specify VAT in an order?

Tags: stripe-payments

We're based in the EU. When we sell our digital products to private persons or companies without a VAT number, we have to charge them VAT (Value Added Tax). This is what I'm trying:

```
import stripe

stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_xxx'
stripe.api_version = '2015-10-16'

product = stripe.Product.create(
    id='product', 
    name='Product', 
    shippable=False
)

sku = stripe.SKU.create(
    product='product', 
    price=100, 
    currency='eur', 
    inventory={'type': 'infinite'}
)

customer = stripe.Customer.create(
    email='customer@example.org',
    description="Customer"
)

order = stripe.Order.create(
    customer=customer.id,
    currency='eur',
    items=[
        {
            'type': 'sku',
            'quantity': 5,
            'parent': sku.id,
            'amount': 500
        },
        {
            'type': 'tax',
            'description': "20% VAT",
            'amount': 100
        }
    ]
)
```

The Order creation call gives me:

> **stripe.error.InvalidRequestError**: Request **req_xxx**: Items of type **tax** are not supported at order creation.

When I replace the last order creation call without the tax:

```
order = stripe.Order.create(
    customer=customer.id,
    currency='eur',
    items=[
        {
            'type': 'sku',
            'quantity': 5,
            'parent': sku.id,
            'amount': 500
        }
    ]
)
```

I'm getting back these `order['items']`:

```
  [
    {
      "amount": 500, 
      "currency": "eur", 
      "description": "Product", 
      "object": "order_item", 
      "parent": "sku_xxx", 
      "quantity": 5, 
      "type": "sku"
    }, 
    {
      "amount": 0, 
      "currency": "eur", 
      "description": "Taxes (included)", 
      "object": "order_item", 
      "parent": null, 
      "quantity": null, 
      "type": "tax"
    }, 
    {
      "amount": 0, 
      "currency": "eur", 
      "description": "Free shipping", 
      "object": "order_item", 
      "parent": "ship_free-shipping", 
      "quantity": null, 
      "type": "shipping"
    }
  ]
```

However, an order does not allow updating the `items` field after the order has been created.

What's the correct and semantic way to add VAT to the order items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Stripe support and this should now be possible in a private beta. You can ask Stripe to join the taxes beta.

After joining, you can access documentation here: https://stripe.com/docs/relay#shipping-and-taxes and here: https://stripe.com/docs/relay/dynamic-shipping-taxes#order-creation-event.

There will be an option in your Stripe dashboard (Relay settings) to specify a "dynamic" taxes webhook where Stripe sends an Order to, and your server should then respond with a Order Item containing a tax entry. The webhook is hit immediately after creating an Order.